# What is difference between the function numpy.dot(), @, and method .dot() for matrix-matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Is there any difference? If not, what is preferred by convention?
The performance seems to be almost the same.

```
a=np.random.rand(1000,1000)
b=np.random.rand(1000,1000)
%timeit a.dot(b)     #14.3 ms ± 374 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.dot(a,b)  #14.7 ms ± 315 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit a @ b        #15.1 ms ± 779 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: For your 2d example, they are essentially the same.  There isn't a `convention` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all basically doing the same thing. In terms of timing, based on Numpy's documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

- If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors
  (without complex conjugation).
- If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but
  using `matmul` or `a @ b` is preferred.
- If either a or b is 0-D (scalar), it is equivalent to multiply and
  using `numpy.multiply(a, b)` or `a * b` is preferred.
- If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over
  the last axis of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 5):

They are almost identical with a few exceptions.

`a.dot(b)` and `np.dot(a, b)` are exactly the same. See [`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) and [`ndarray.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dot.html).

However, looking at the documentation of `numpy.dot`:

> If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using `matmul` or `a @ b` is preferred.

`a @ b` corresponds to [`numpy.matmul(a, b)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html). `dot` and `matmul` differ as follows:

> `matmul` differs from `dot` in two important ways:
>
> - Multiplication by scalars is not allowed, use `*` instead.
> - Stacks of matrices are broadcast together as if the matrices were
>     elements, respecting the signature `(n,k),(k,m)->(n,m)`:
>
> ```
> >>> a = np.ones([9, 5, 7, 4])
> >>> c = np.ones([9, 5, 4, 3])
> >>> np.dot(a, c).shape (9, 5, 7, 9, 5, 3)
> >>> np.matmul(a, c).shape (9, 5, 7, 3)
> >>> # n is 7, k is 4, m is 3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, what best description and explanation is a clear example:

```
# How and when to use dot or matmul (@) ? # suppose all B values of dense nnet is 0 

inp=np.random.random((20,10,100,4)) # 4 inputs 100 data 10 different cases 20 different groups
nnet1=np.random.random((4,3)) # 4 inputs 3 outputs 
nnet2=np.random.random((3,5)) # 3 inputs 5 outputs 
nnet3=np.random.random((5,2)) # 5 inputs 2 outputs 

test1=inp@nnet1@nnet2@nnet3
test2=inp.dot(nnet1).dot(nnet2).dot(nnet3)
print(test1.shape)
print(test2.shape)
print(test1[5,3,7,1]) #6 th data 4th case second nnet output
print(test2[5,3,7,1]) #6 th data 4th case second nnet output



inp=np.random.random((20,10,100,4)) # 4 inputs 100 data 10 different cases 20 different groups
nnet1=np.random.random((9,4,3)) # 4 inputs 3 outputs  # 9 different networks
nnet2=np.random.random((9,3,5)) # 3 inputs 5 outputs  # 9 different networks
nnet3=np.random.random((9,5,2)) # 5 inputs 2 outputs  # 9 different networks 

test1=inp@nnet1[0]@nnet2[0]@nnet3[0]  # for network 0 
test2=inp.dot(nnet1@nnet2@nnet3)
print(test1.shape)
print(test2.shape)
print(test1[5,3,7,1]) #6 th data 4th case second nnet output
print(test2[5,3,7,0,1]) # 6 th data 4th case second nnet output for network 0
```

Output:

```
(20, 10, 100, 2)
(20, 10, 100, 2)
2.502277900709035
2.502277900709035
(20, 10, 100, 2)
(20, 10, 100, 9, 2)
0.6919054739155295
0.6919054739155295
```

Where you can compare and contrast each element to conditionally connect them which makes you understand deeply ...