# Differences between matrix multiplication using numpy.dot(m1, m2) vs m1.dot(m2)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray

I'm just getting started with `numpy` and came across this 'dilemma'.

Suppose I have two matrices `m1` and `m2`. There is `numpy.dot(a, b, out=None)` function, so I can call `numpy.dot(m1, m2)`. But then there's also `ndarray.dot(b, out=None)`, i.e. I can call `m1.dot(m2)`. So which one should I use? Are there any differences between both methods? Pros/cons?

Comment: This is the same. In fact, if you look at how `ndarray` works, it will fallback on the `numpy.dot`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517281/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-a-dotb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between the function numpy.dot(), @, and method .dot() for matrix-matrix multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416178/what-is-difference-between-the-function-numpy-dot-and-method-dot-for-ma)